# Is it possible to dynamically bind operator>?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, operators, virtual-functions, dynamic-binding

Dynamic bound requires that a virtual function should have the same parameter list in a base class and its derived class. This makes me wonder whether operator> could be dynamically bounden? The following demo seems to prove that it cannot.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
struct B
{
    B(int b = 0):m_b(b){}
    virtual bool operator>(const B& rhs)const {cout << "B::operator>" << endl;return m_b > rhs.m_b;}
    int m_b;
};

struct D: public B
{
    D(int b = 0, long d = 0):B(b),m_d(d){}
    virtual bool operator>(const D& rhs)const {cout << "D::operator>" << endl; return m_d > rhs.m_d;}
    long m_d;
};
int main() 
{
    D d1(0,0),d2(1,-1);
    B& b1(d1),b2(d2);

    cout << (b1 > b2) << endl;
    cout << "------------" << endl;
    cout << (d1 > d2) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

output:

```
B::operator>
0
------------
D::operator>
1
```

Comment: The signatures don't match, you aren't overriding the base function (tip: use `override` to check). Operators are just functions and so can be `virtual`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
virtual bool operator>(const D& rhs)const {
  cout << "D::operator>" << endl;
  return m_d > rhs.m_d;
}
virtual bool operator>(const B& rhs)const override final {
  if(D const*=dynamic_cast<D const*>(&rhs))
    return *this>*other;
  return B::operator>(rhs);
}
```

fixes your problem.  It now does double dispatch on both arguments, and if they both are `D` it calls the proper overload.  Otherwise it relies on `B`'s version.

There are many ways to do double dispatch in C++, they all must be done manually.

Comment: As an aside, `override final` prevents further derived classes from trying to overload the base class's `operator>` -- instead, they are supposed to override `D`'s `operator>`, possibly with a similar check, and do the same `override final` on their override while creating a new `virtual` same-type overload.  Note that if the static type of both arguments is known at the call site, it dispatches strait to the `D const&` one without a dynamic cast.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the same signature in the derived than in the base, so that it effectively overrides the base:

```
struct D: public B
{
    D(int b = 0, long d = 0):B(b),m_d(d){}
    bool operator>(const B& rhs)const override {  cout << "D::operator>" << endl; return m_d > static_cast<const D*>(&rhs)->m_d;}
    long m_d;
};
```